# How to put IF condition in where section of select command in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, select

I declare some filters on a form and pass them into my SP in SQL for running a select command and this is how I did that, but it didn't work:

```
DECLARE @Confirm_Filter AS BIT=NULL,
@ReciveDate_Filter AS NCHAR(10) = NULL
....
select * from .......
where 
(@Confirm_Filter IS NOT NULL AND InterviewConfirm = @Confirm_Filter)
AND
(@ReciveDate_Filter  IS NOT NULL AND ReciveDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND @ReciveDate_Filter)
```

and in the where section I want to do:

```
where 
if @Confirm_Filter IS NOT NULL Then (Select * from ... where InterviewConfirm = @Confirm_Filter)
AND
if @ReciveDate_Filter  IS NOT NULL Then (select * from .... where ReciveDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND @ReciveDate_Filter)
```

and I know above form is totally mistake but how could I do it?

Comment: Ahh Dale, you edited off the asap part huh? I was inclined to mention it in an answer.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add urgent or other similar phrases to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: You need to clarify your question, are you trying to pull data from 2 different tables? Consider providing sample data and desired results for extra clarity.

Comment: I want to join some table and select this filters on it. instead of 'IF' condition I use 'AND' operator but didn't worked

Comment: You might want to investigate the use of `OR` in addition to `AND` - if you require all conditions to be true you're never going to get many results.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is called dynamic search conditions. It is solved either by using dynamic SQL, or the following pattern (which is similar to your first version, but with a few changes):

```
select * from .......
where 
(@Confirm_Filter IS NULL OR InterviewConfirm = @Confirm_Filter)
AND
(@ReciveDate_Filter  IS NULL OR ReciveDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND @ReciveDate_Filter)
```

Comment: Key being `OR` instead of `AND`.

Comment: I use this way but didn't return anything.

Comment: Well, go ahead and test then! First, set both variables to null and you should see the whole table. Then, test more. I would hazard a guess there is a type mismatch between the @ReciveData_Filter and the ReciveDate field itself. Are they both datetime?

Comment: when filters set to null return anything but when those are set to not null return data. actually I set filters to Null for could ignore some of it but when it set to null return anything

Comment: @MHD then you need to provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results, because this solution works in principle... so it must be something specific to your situation that isn't working.

Comment: thank you . i didn't attention you change not null to null in  (@Confirm_Filter IS NULL OR InterviewConfirm = @Confirm_Filter). it worked now